# haskell list comprehension non termination

Tags: haskell

I have code:

```
import Data.List

triangles :: [Int]
triangles = takeWhile (\n -> factors n /= 0) [n * (n + 1) `div` 2 | n <- [1..]]
triangles' = takeWhile (/= 0) [n * (n + 1) `div` 2 | n <- [1..]]

intSqrt :: Int -> Int 
intSqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

factors :: Int -> Int 
factors n = 2 * length facs
    where facs = takeWhile (<= intSqrt n) [x | x <- [1..], n `mod` x == 0]
```

`triangles'` prints a ton of numbers instantly, whereas `triangles` gets stuck before printing anything at all. I saw a similar problem which was caused by infinite mutual recursion, but I don't think I've introduced any recursion here.

Comment: How is this down-voted the second after I posted it ?!!!

Comment: I also wonder why it was downvoted..

Comment: I did get a warning to modify my title before I could submit, but it would suck if that automatically downvotes

Comment: I don't think there is such a functionality on SO.. Anyway, to your question. Are you sure any of the numbers generated by `[n * (n + 1) `div` 2 | n <- [1..]]` will satisfy `factors n == 0` ? Update: Ok, you have got an answer..

Comment: @rem Not the downvoter, but I'd say the reason might have been because you don't actually have a question in this post.  Your title is also pretty poorly worded.  Users of So really prefer good grammar and well worded posts.  For one thing, putting "haskell" in the title doesn't help much when you've tagged the post with "haskell".  Again, I'm not the one who gave you a downvote, just trying to give a critique of what others may find wrong with your post so that in the future you can try to avoid those mistakes.  Better questions, even ones with simple solutions, make SO better for everyone =)

Comment: thanks @bheklilr, I'll watch out in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `factors 1` doesn't terminate. The `takeWhile` looks at the input until it finds a factor greater than `intSqrt 1`, but there are no such factors.

You could simplify the list comprehension to avoid the `takeWhile` altogether:

```
facs = [x | x <- [1..intSqrt n], n `mod` x == 0]
```